# CSS: div with cross label and horizontal label

Tags: css

I was looking at a post [here](http://speckyboy.com/2009/02/19/12-wordpress-plugins-to-display-and-highlight-code-within-your-blog/) and noticed that the snapshots have a side label bar and a botton horizontal bar for labeling contents.

How can this be achieved using CSS?

Update: I am talking about the cross-bar in the first image that says "snapshot" and "WP Advanced Code Editor"!

Comment: What bars are you talking about??

Comment: horizontal bar is easy using div with position absolute, But top right is tricky you have to use CSS3 transform & many other things of css3

Comment: @SVS - can you plz point me to any resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/hEeZA/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="diag"> Some text </span>
    <span class="horiz"> Some text </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    background: beige;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

span {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

.horiz {
    bottom: 40px;
}

.diag {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
       -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
            transform:rotate(45deg);

    right: -50px;
    top: 30px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My demo can be seen here http://dabblet.com/gist/3152262

I have an image wrapper with `overflow:hidden` and I've simply used a `:before` pseudo-element which I've rotated and absolutely positioned. Same idea for the horizontal one.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="img.jpg">
</a>
```

CSS

```
.img-wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.img-wrapper:before, .img-wrapper:after {
    padding: .3em 2.9em;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    font: 700 14px sans-serif;
}
.img-wrapper:before {
    top: 35px;
    right: -40px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: 'Screenshot';
}
.img-wrapper:after {
    top: 85%;
    content: 'Developer Formatter'
}
```